# Service reference to remote WCF service still accessing local service

Tags: wcf

I developed a WCF service hosted by the managed windows service on my local machine and a client which was consuming that service and everything works fine on my dev box...

To install on the test server I changed the config file for my windows service from

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/RemoteServices/MyService/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

to

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress = "http://someremoteserver:8733/RemoteServices/MyService/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

and started the windows service on the remote server.

In my client which consumes the WCF service I removed the Service Reference that was connecting to WCF service on my local machine and added a new reference using the remote machine address

```
http://someremoteserver:8733/RemoteServices/MyService/mex
```

and it apparently connected to the remote server and retrieved WCF service information from the remote server, however, when I start the client and try to consume the remote service it still connects to my local service and when I shut down the local windows service hosting WCF service I get:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost

message.

What is going on here and how do I get the client to connect to the remote service, not the local service?

Comment: You should have both client-side and server-side binding configuration, either defined in a .config file, or defined programmatically.  You said you changed your config for the service, but what about your binding config at the client?  How is your binding config set up at the client?  We would need you to share that info to be able to help.

Comment: @Jim, Yes that was the problem, the app.config file of my client still had localhost address... I thought removing and adding a Service Reference was all that was needed... post it as answer and I'll accept...

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.  I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side binding config, usually in the client's app.config file, needs to be updated to have the correct endpoint URL.

Comment: Why didn't it get updated when I removed the local service reference and added the reference to the remote service?